# Refresh datagrid from child window

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

Let consider I have two windows, window1 contains one datagrid and one button, when I click in this button it sends me to window2 to fill some fields then save the record in the database, the problem is when wondow2 is closed I cannot see this record in the datagrid in windows1 directly.

Comment: You need to explain more for useful help. As described above, you can just get some simple answers. One of them is that after some fields are saved in window2, refresh window1 for displaying the fields. Another is that when window2 is closed, send the saved fields to window1 for displaying.

Comment: 1 - Post the relevant code and XAML. 2 - This is easily resolved at the ViewModel level by raising an event in the Child ViewModel and having the Parent ViewModel listen to that event.

Comment: Thanks both for the answer, I solved it using option 1. After runing the segun window I refresh the data grid.